# Retrieving data from a database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite database that is populated when the user create a profile and fill a form with his contact informations in `SetUpProfile` activity and then retrieve that data and show it back on `UserProfile` activity.

**Question:** How to display the profile data (name, phone, address...) in textviews ?

This is what I've done so far:

**Profile class**

```
public class Profile {
private int _id = 1;
private String _industryName;
private String _industryType;
private String _email;
private String _phone;
private String _address;
private String _packageType;

public Profile() {
    /** stays empty */
}

public Profile(int _id, String _industryName, String _industryType, String _email, String _phone, String _address, String _packageType) {
    this._id = _id;
    this._industryName = _industryName;
    this._industryType = _industryType;
    this._email = _email;
    this._phone = _phone;
    this._address = _address;
    this._packageType = _packageType;
}

public Profile(String _industryName, String _industryType, String _email, String _phone, String _address, String _packageType) {
    this._industryName = _industryName;
    this._industryType = _industryType;
    this._email = _email;
    this._phone = _phone;
    this._address = _address;
    this._packageType = _packageType;
}
   //getters and setters
}
```

This is the handler **DBHandler class**

**addProfile() method:**

```
    public void addProfile(Profile profile) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_INDUSTRY_NAME, profile.get_industryName());
    values.put(KEY_INDUSTRY_TYPE, profile.get_industryType());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, profile.get_email());
    values.put(KEY_PHONE, profile.get_phone());
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, profile.get_address());
    values.put(KEY_PACKAGE_TYPE, profile.get_packageType());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_PROFILE, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

**getProfile() method**

```
public Profile getProfile(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PROFILE, new String[] {
            KEY_ID, KEY_INDUSTRY_NAME, KEY_INDUSTRY_TYPE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PHONE, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_PACKAGE_TYPE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Profile profile = new Profile(
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1),
            cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(3),
            cursor.getString(4),
            cursor.getString(5),
            cursor.getString(6)
    );

    return profile;
    }
```

**MainActivity class**

```
public class UserProfile extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

    //SQLite databes is supposed to populate those textViews
    industry_type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b_industry);
    b_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b_industry_name);
    b_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mail);
    b_phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    b_address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
    plan_type = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p_title);

    edit_profile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editProfile);

    industry_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    plan_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.plan_icon);


    edit_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditProfile();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is EditProfile() function?

Comment: @PriyankPatel it's not needed for the moment, I posted only the relevant code to keep the question clean and straight forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I used :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
DBHandler dd = new DBHandler(getBaseContext());
dd.getWritableDatabase();
db= openOrCreateDatabase("profileManager.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
Cursor cc = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM profile", null);
if(cc.getCount()>=1) {
    cc.moveToFirst();
    try {
        for(int i=0;i < cc.getCount();i++){
            bname = cc.getString(1);
            btype = cc.getString(2);
            bmail = cc.getString(3);
            bphone = cc.getString(4);
            baddress = cc.getString(5);
            bpackage = cc.getString(6);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create getters of your private variables of profile class. For example as below.

```
public String getIndustryName() {
  return _industryName;
}
```

Then you need to call `getProfile()` method from your activity class which return `Profile` object.

From `Profile` object, you can get all value and set it into relevent `TextView` and display. For example as below.

```
b_name.setText(profile.getIndustryName());
```

Comment: the getters are up and running I just didn't want to flood the question with extra pieces of code

Comment: Can you just put logs in `getProfile()` function and check what values you are getting from database?